# Nested data for forum

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

Got myself stuck...

Us left and right limits in nested set model to store forum posts and I need to select threads ordered by latest reply.

Relevant table structure:

```
id  lft  rght date
1   1    4    2011-01-01
2   5    8    2011-01-02
3   6    7    2011-01-04
4   2    3    2011-01-05
```

so from that I need to get

```
id last_reply latest
1  4          2011-01-05
2  6          2011-01-04
```

any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  pt.*, MAX(pc.date) AS latest
FROM    post pt
JOIN    post pc
ON      pc.lft BETWEEN pt.lft AND pt.rgt
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    post pu
        WHERE   pt.lft BETWEEN pu.lft AND pu.rgt
        )
GROUP BY
        pt.id
ORDER BY
        latest DESC
```

Nested sets is not good for selecting the depth level so this is not going to be efficient.

I would suggest storing the thread started `id` along with each post and create a composite index on `(starter, date)`.

This way, you could just use:

```
SELECT  pt.*,
        MAX(date) AS latest
FROM    post pu
JOIN    post pt
ON      pt.id = pu.starter
GROUP BY
        pu.starter
ORDER BY
        latest DESC
```

which would be much faster.

Comment: Cheers Quassnoi - I was convincing myself I didn't need to revisit the data structure - but that was sheer vanity. thanks matey...